# Programming question in context of Raspberry PI - Does it belong here?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic, questions

I posted [a question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14406/13332) almost an hour ago. The topic of the question is heavily programming related (in Java). The library I'm using is not Raspberry-specific; its a general audio library included in the Java JDK. Despite that, it is relevant in the context of the Pi because it relates to an issue I have thus far **only** observed on the PI.

I was unsure from the beginning whether my question was more appropriate on Stackoverflow, or to post it here. I checked out the [on-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page, and thought that the question was appropriate because:

- It satisfied the on-topic requirement: *Software that runs on the Raspberry Pi*
- And did not satisfy the off-topic requirement: *Questions about programming that are not related to its usage on the Raspberry Pi. These will probably be better off on Programmers or Stackoverflow.*

I notice it is not receiving a lot of views, which has me wondering more so whether this was the appropriate place. I'm not sure whether the Raspberry SE community is more software or hardware-oriented (or a mix of both). Ultimately, since I will be doing a ton of programming on the Raspberry for the next little while, I might be posting again, so I want to see whether such questions are better served here, or on Stackoverflow.

In short, is my question relevant to the Raspberry PI SE site?

*P.S: Not to worry, I'm not feeling impatient, I basically want to know where questions like this are better served*

**Edit:** It seems [this person](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14387/13332) is wondering the same thing in regards to their question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that there is a clear choice here. I think that the question you linked to is clearly better here than on another SE site, because it only manifests itself on the Raspberry Pi. So answers may best come from others with Pi experience.

As for the question of page views understand that your particular question is fairly specific, as a result their may not be many people who have experience both with the Pi and utilizing Java (and the specific libraries) used to play sounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you're right, from what I've seen the skill-types of the users on this SE are quite varied, meaning not everyone here is a computer programmer. I'll keep it here since, like you said, it only manifests on the PI.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Steve. It does depend on whether or not it *only* appears on the Raspberry Pi.

If you have a Python script, C program, Java applet, etc. that runs just fine on your regular system, but is returning an error or acting irregularly on the Pi, I believe it would be considered on-topic here.

However, if it is an error that manifests itself more-or-less the same on both the Raspberry Pi and another *regular* (PC/Mac) system, then I believe it would be better on another site such as, like you said, Stack Overflow.

Many errors *can* only happen on the Pi, such as GPIO or Raspberry Cam related issues, and those, in my opinion, should be considered on-topic explicitly.

Like Steve said, it depends on a lot. If you think you are going to get better answers for your issue here, post it here. We can always have it transferred to the correct site later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree, I figured the fact that it only manifests on the PI is reason enough to keep it here. Good overall guidelines.